# How to sort a particular page in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, paging

Here is the part of the code:

```
private void BindData()
{  
       .................
      sda.Fill(ds);
      if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
      {
        DataView DV = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        if (Session["sortBy"] != null) 
        {
            DV.Sort = Session["sortBy"].ToString();
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = DV;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

}

Code for sorting:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

Session["sortBy"] = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
BindData();
```

}

```
private string GetSortDirection(string column)
{


string sortDirection = "ASC";

string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

if (sortExpression != null)
{

    if (sortExpression == column)
    {
        string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
        if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
        {
            sortDirection = "DESC";
        }
    }
}

ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

return sortDirection;
}
```

Paging part is working fine and when i sort the page, all data in the datasource is getting sorted but I want to sort only a particular page in the gridview. How to achieve tat?

Comment: Set Session["sortBy"] = null; in gridview page index change before bind the grid.

Comment: Here's a useful link showing how to do that. http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/08/sorting-only-current-page-of-gridview.html

Comment: you can do it by some logic but your code will be messed up and actual business may not survive, instead you can maintain sorted data while page index. in sorting event, store the data table in 'viewstate' that you sorted and when page index was changed bind the data from view state. so when user changed page index grid view will show the sorted data only.
one more suggestion is application should not hit database until fetch criteria not changed. Store the data table in 'viewstate' or 'session' 'object' and use the same for sorting and paging

Comment: @Raghubar: i tried its not working